# Is syntax highlighting broken?

Tags: bug

I usually use fenced code blocks in order to get code
syntax-highlighted, as in

````
```c++
some C++ source
```
````

This used to work for quite some time. However, since a couple of days
or so, it looks like it doesn't work anymore.

Examples: [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/76446/7508) and [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/76397/7508).

The weird thing is: while editing, the syntax highlighting does work in
the preview... sometimes!

Did I do something wrong? Is this feature deprecated? Is it just a
glitch in the Matrix?

Comment: 2020-06-17: Arduino Stack Exchange was migrated to CommonMark. use ```cpp

Answer (score 3):

I removed the `c++` in the first question, and now the syntax highlighting is working.

If it worked before (with the `c++`), my best guess is Stack Exchange made some changes in the back end.

There is another way to force syntax highlighting for **all** code blocks in a particular Q or A.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-cpp -->
```

There is more information here: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and according to this page, the `c++` **should** work.

Clearly there is something wrong or something changed. I'll see what I can find out...

Comment: Thanks! I knew about this option, but I find it somewhat clumsy. I prefer fenced code blocks and have been using them since I noticed stackexchange started supporting them.

Comment: You might also need to add a space **``` cpp** - it's another commonmark thing

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by VE7JRO, the language can be specified using a
specially-formatted HTML comment.

For those who prefer the more standard “fenced code blocks”, my tests
show they still work when the fence is labeled `cpp` or `lang-cpp`, but
not with the labels `c++` or `lang-c++`:

````
```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)  // be insistent
    Serial.println("Hello!");
```
````

is rendered:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)  // be insistent
    Serial.println("Hello!");
```

**Edit**: This may be the cause of the issue:
[We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746).